# can't use composer in php 7.3?

Tags: composer-php, centos7, yum

i tried to install composer by yum in centos but failed.
this error i got after tried.

```
Error: Package: composer-1.7.2-1.el7.noarch (epel)
       Requires: php-zip
       Available: php-common-5.4.16-45.el7.x86_64 (base)
           php-zip
.
.
.
       Available: php72w-common-7.2.10-1.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-zip
       Installed: php-common-7.3.0~rc4-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php73)
           Not found
       Available: php-common-7.3.0~rc3-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
           Not found
```

Comment: This might be better over on [su] - It looks like your installing things from different repos hence your problem with finding stuff.

Comment: no, i installed by root user

Comment: It may be installed by root - but look at where from; `composer-1.7.2-1.el7.noarch` from `EPEL` looking for php versions from `remi-php73` and `webtatic` repos. What version of php do you have installed ? `rpm -q php`

Comment: Disable webtatic ("remi-php73" is the only with 7.3 available for now)